# How to limit the Storage IO with ArangoDB?

Tags: io, storage, arangodb

How to limit the Storage IO with ArangoDB? I have no problem with CPU or memory (RAM) but the disk (NAS) behind it has limited IO capacity. With InnoDB under MySQL you can limit it with “**innodb_io_capacity**=xxx”. What is the way or command under ArangoDB? If I look under “iotop”, arangodb is running permanently with several processes on 100% in our case and so it loads the storage medium completely. Also the “WAL sync happens longer than” errors appear in the logfile. Our server: 24 CPUs, 60 GB Ram. The DB does not run as a cluster. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Would you have any iotop output, please? And could you describe the workload a bit. How have you created the collections? Were they created with the `waitForSync` option set? What operating system? Which version of ArangoDB?

Comment: In a much smaller test environment, everything runs fine. Wait for sync is everywhere off and all collections have corresponding indexes. Ultimately, it is not because of our database itself, but because ArangoDB takes the entire IO and brings the NAS to the limit. With a mysql it is similar, it also takes all IO until you limit the IO capacity. Then everything runs great. We also need this on ArangoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I have since spoken to someone at ArangoDB. Currently there is actually no setting to limit the IO of ArangoDB. The server takes as much IO as it can and loads the whole system with it. Unfortunately, this leads to performance issues on a NAS storage.

I have posted an issue about this on Github and hope ArangoDB will update the setting: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/14385